# c# Linq to XML load List in object

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I would like save and Load this Class in XML with Linq:

```
public class AssemblyVerwaltung
{
    public string AssemblyName;
    public List<string> List_KlassenNamen;
}
```

In Form1 i have a List of this Class:

```
List<AssemblyVerwaltung> List_AssemblyVerwaltung;
```

The Save mehtode looks like that

```
void Save(XMLPath)
{
   //need help hear
   //Save List of "AssemblyVerwaltung" with Linq to XML
}
```

and the Load Mehtode looks like that

```
void LoadXML(XMLPath)
{
  List_AssemblyVerwaltung = //need help hear (load XML with Linq)
}
```

Comment: Why not use `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: Thank you. My solution until now is:

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one root node in XML.  So you have to wrap the code with a Root Element.  Try code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<AssemblyVerwaltung> List_AssemblyVerwaltung = new List<AssemblyVerwaltung>();
            Root root = new Root();
            root.List_AssemblyVerwaltung = new List<AssemblyVerwaltung>(List_AssemblyVerwaltung);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces _ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            _ns.Add("", "");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, root, _ns);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Root  newRoot = (Root)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }

    }
    [XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement("List_AssemblyVerwaltung")]
        public List<AssemblyVerwaltung> List_AssemblyVerwaltung  { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("List_AssemblyVerwaltung")]
    public class AssemblyVerwaltung
    {
        [XmlElement("AssemblyName")]
        public string AssemblyName {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("List_KlassenNamen")]
        public List<string> List_KlassenNamen {get;set;}
    }


}
```